# How to build a static project in QT?

Tags: qt

How to build a static project in QT?
I would like to see step by step instructions.
My version qt 5.12.2
OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What's a "static project"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build Qt itself statically. Instructions:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-building.html

To do a static build, pass the `-static` flag to `./configure`. You might want to install this in your home directory instead of system wide. In that case, also pass something like `-prefix $HOME/custom_qt/5.12.3` so that this Qt build will be installed in your home directory when you do `make install`.

Building is going to take a long time, so make sure to use `make -jN` to build it (replace `N` with the amount of threads/cores your CPU has.) It will still take a long time even with that, so you should probably disable Qt modules you don't need (like the webkit module). If you downloaded the complete source package of Qt (like https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.3/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3.tar.xz), then you should simply delete the subdirectories of the modules you don't need **before** calling `./configure`.

Once you've built and installed it successfully, you need to build your application using this version of Qt. If your application uses qmake, then use `~/custom_qt/5.12.3/bin/qmake` to configure and build it.

---

**Alternative to static building**
Note that instead of using static linking, you can instead use normal dynamic linking but package your application as an AppImage using the [linuxdeployqt](https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt) tool. More info on AppImage:

https://appimage.org

Comment: I execute the command: `/home/user/Downloads/linuxdeployqt-6-x86_64.AppImage /home/user/projects/qtpro/build-mycpptest-Desktop_Qt_5_12_3_GCC_64bit-Release/mycpptest -unsupported-allow-new-glibc -appimage`

Comment: Writes me: `fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
NOTE: Using the output of 'git rev-parse --short HEAD' as the version:
      Please set the $VERSION environment variable if this is not intended
Categories entry not found in desktop file
.desktop file is missing a Categories= key`

Comment: Success! It was necessary to register in default.desktop Categories = GTK; GNOME; Thank you very much!

Comment: @AngelPensive `Categories` should be one of these: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.0.html#category-registry